# mysql group by with repeated value and count

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a query with group by but i want to repeat values with count , for example , my result like this :

my query is :

SELECT 
s.id,s.user_id,s.start_date,s.end_date,count(s.user_id) as num_of_subscriptions
FROM 
subscriptions s join users u on (s.user_id= u.id )
GROUP BY s.user_id;

id     user_id     start_date    end_date     number_of_subscription

1      2           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     4

2      5           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     3

i want to get data like this

id     user_id     start_date    end_date     number_of_subscription

1      2           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     4

1      2           2016-05-10    2016-05-21     4

1      2           2016-05-11    2016-05-21     4

1      2           2016-05-12    2016-05-21     4

2      5           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     3

2      5           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     3

2      5           2016-05-20    2016-05-21     3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a sub query rather than a group by so 
given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(user_id int,start_date date,end_date date);
insert into t values
( 2 ,'2016-05-20' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 2 ,'2016-05-10' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 2 ,'2016-05-11' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 2 ,'2016-05-12' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 5 ,'2016-05-20' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 5 ,'2016-05-20' ,'2016-05-21'),
( 5 ,'2016-05-20' ,'2016-05-21');
```

This

```
select user_id,start_date,end_date, (select count(*) from t t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id)
from t t
```

Results in

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | start_date | end_date   | (select count(*) from t t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id) |

    +---------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
    |       2 | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        4 |
    |       2 | 2016-05-10 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        4 |
    |       2 | 2016-05-11 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        4 |
    |       2 | 2016-05-12 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        4 |
    |       5 | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        3 |
    |       5 | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        3 |
    |       5 | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-21 |                                                        3 |
    +---------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```